# Header spacing on second page in sale order report

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

[image]

Hello to all,

I have created my custom report in sale order for Odoo 10 but i have this problem with overlapping the header and body on the second page when i have more products in the Quotation.

Can someone help how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have made your own custom header.So now you can set your company logo in fixed size and you can fix your issue.You can edit the logo size.

Like this....

```xml
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <img t-if="o.company_id.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % o.company_id.logo"
     style="max-height:170px; max-width:170px;" />
</div>
```